# Always focus on custom TextField no matter what

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following component which uses the TextField:

```js
const BarcodeField = ({disableEnter, ...rest})=>{
   return <TextField {...(disableEnter && { onKeyDown: {(e)=>e.key === 'Enter' && e.preventDefault()} })} {...rest}>
}
```

and I consume it somewhere else as follows:

```js
import BarcodeField from '...etc path'
const PosCalculator = ()=>{
  return (
     <>
        <BarcodeField disableEnter fullWidth />
     </>
  )
}
```

I want to set the `BarcodeField` from the `PosCalculator` component focused forever, even if the user clicked outside the component on the body of the page.

But how?

- I want also to be able to toggle the force focus state based on a condition

Comment: Did you try passing useRef hook to the TextField component to focus on the element?

Comment: yes I tried, but it's more complex than it seems, if you tried it you'll see what I mean, it did not work the same way I am expecting it to work

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try this:

```
const inputRef = useRef();
inputRef.current.focus() //inside useEffect
```

This is just an idea